# Google charts LineGraph switching datatables and maintaining state

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have tweaked a few examples I found across the net that allow me to remove/greyout a series when it is clicked (legend or line itself).

I then wanted to add ability to switch between datatables and have what was hidden/greyedout to transfer to the new datatable.

I took the idea from switching data from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#value-changes
(my graphs are not animating correctly like the example)

My problem is I get very weird results when clicking on the "Switch" button and switching datatables, sometimes it will keep the correct selection but when you click on a different series one will magically appear or it will deselect a different series than the one clicked. I can't figure out to get it so both datatables maintain the same selection (selection meaning greyed out/removed series).

It's worth noting that

```
         columns.push({
            calc: 'stringify',
            sourceColumn: i,
            type: 'string',
            role: 'annotation'
         });
```

is adding hidden columns to aide in additional logic for the series. While I am not directly using it currently I want it to remain and work properly because I think I will use it in the future. These "hidden" columns add complexity where I think the bug lives.

The code is here:

```
var button = document.getElementById('b1');
var current = 0;
var data = [];
var chart;
var options;
var ms2 = [{
   "LOCAL_ID": "W-133",
   "Class1": 29,
   "Class2": 3628,
   "Class3": 159,
   "Class4": 24,
   "Class5": 65,
   "Class6": 12,
   "Class7": 0,
   "Class8": 12,
   "Class9": 110,
   "Class10": 41,
   "Class11": 0,
   "Class12": 0,
   "Class13": 0
}, {
   "LOCAL_ID": "14-6A-060",
   "Class1": 19,
   "Class2": 290,
   "Class3": 224,
   "Class4": 0,
   "Class5": 0,
   "Class6": 0,
   "Class7": 0,
   "Class8": 2,
   "Class9": 0,
   "Class10": 0,
   "Class11": 1,
   "Class12": 0,
   "Class13": 0
}, {
   "LOCAL_ID": "45-5-006",
   "Class1": 7,
   "Class2": 191,
   "Class3": 165,
   "Class4": 0,
   "Class5": 6,
   "Class6": 3,
   "Class7": 0,
   "Class8": 4,
   "Class9": 18,
   "Class10": 11,
   "Class11": 0,
   "Class12": 0,
   "Class13": 10
}];



google.charts.load('current', {
   'packages': ['line']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(init);


button.onclick = function() {
   current = 1 - current;
   button.disabled = true;
   options.chart['subtitle'] = (current ? 'View 1' : 'View 2');
   chart.draw(data[current], options);
};


function getData() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

   data.addColumn('number', 'Class');
   ms2.forEach(function(masterLocation, index) {
      data.addColumn('number', masterLocation.LOCAL_ID);
   });

   for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
      var arr = [i];
      ms2.forEach(function(masterLocation, index) {
         arr.push(masterLocation['Class' + i]);
      });

      data.addRow(arr);
   }

   return data;
}

function getRandomData(base) {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('number', 'Class');
   data.addColumn('number', ms2[0].LOCAL_ID);
   data.addColumn('number', ms2[1].LOCAL_ID);
   data.addColumn('number', ms2[2].LOCAL_ID);


   // add random data
   var y1 = base,
      y2 = base,
      y3 = base;
   for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
      y1 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
      y2 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
      y3 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
      data.addRow([i, y1, y2, y3]);
   }

   return data;
}

function init() {
   data = [];
   data[0] = getData();
   data[1] = getRandomData(1000);
   chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

   options = {
      chart: {
         title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
         subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
      },
      width: 500,
      height: 300,
      vAxis: {
         gridlines: {
            color: '#ccc'
         }
      },
      hAxis: {
         gridlines: {
            color: '#ccc'
         }
      },
      animation: {
         duration: 1000,
         easing: 'out'
      }
   };

   drawChart();
}


function drawChart() {
   var columns = [];
   var defaultSeries = [1, 2, 3];
   var series = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < data[current].getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      if (i === 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {
         // if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
         columns.push(i);
      } else {
         // otherwise, hide it
         columns.push({
            label: data.getColumnLabel(i),
            type: data.getColumnType(i),
            sourceColumn: i,
            calc: function() {
               return null;
            }
         });
      }
      if (i > 0) {
         columns.push({
            calc: 'stringify',
            sourceColumn: i,
            type: 'string',
            role: 'annotation'
         });
         // set the default series option
         series[i - 1] = {};
         if (defaultSeries.indexOf(i) == -1) {
            // backup the default color (if set)
            if (typeof(series[i - 1].color) !== 'undefined') {
               series[i - 1].backupColor = series[i - 1].color;
            }
            series[i - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
         }
      }
   }

   options['series'] = series;


   function showHideSeries() {
      var sel = chart.getSelection();
      if (sel.length < 1 || sel[0].row) {
         return;
      }

      var col = sel[0].column;
      if (typeof(columns[col]) == 'number') {
         var src = columns[col];


         var calcFunc = null;
         if (document.getElementById("removeSeriesOnSelect").checked) {
            calcFunc = function() {
               return null;
            };
         }

         columns[col] = {
            label: data[current].getColumnLabel(src),
            type: data[current].getColumnType(src),
            sourceColumn: src,
            calc: calcFunc
         };
         // grey out the legend entry
         series[src - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
      } else {
         var src = columns[col].sourceColumn;
         // show the data series
         columns[col] = src;
         series[src - 1].color = null;
      }
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data[current]);
      view.setColumns(columns);

      chart.draw(view, options);
   }


   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);

   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
      button.disabled = false;
   });

   var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data[current]);
   view.setColumns(columns);
   chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sp7atw1L/

Edit: I started a bounty. Given the global variables and maybe the indirect way this is doing things. I am not opposed to a direct refactor/redo that accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the bug is related to annotation columns. After `drawChart()` your columns array is `[0,1,{a},2,{a},3,{a}]`.

```
> when column 1 clicked, everything is ok. 
> when column 2 clicked, columns[2] is {a}, which in your code is replaced by 1, so, you get another copy of column 1
> when column 3 clicked, columns[3] is 2, so, the wrong row is selected
```

These are consequences, but the problem lies in `chart.getSelection()` not taking into account annotation columns and returning wrong indexes. I am not sure why this happens, but if you draw DataView (instead of DataTable) in onclick handler like this

```
 //chart.draw(data[current], options);   <-------remove this

 var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data[current]);
 view.setColumns(columns);// <---make columns global
 chart.draw(view, options);
```

it solves the issue. A related problem with annotations is e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850112/google-charts-select-listener-returns-wrong-column-number)

---

Additionally, in `getData()` the line

```
arr.push(masterLocation['Class' + i]);
```

should be

```
arr.push(masterLocation['Class' + i+1]);
```